# BigQuery - WITH Statement - reference earlier subquery in WHERE condition in later subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Typically a WITH Statement has the following [form](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause)

```
WITH subQ1 AS (SELECT SchoolID FROM Roster),
     subQ2 AS (SELECT OpponentID FROM PlayerStats)
SELECT * FROM subQ1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM subQ2;
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

```
WITH
  relevant_ids AS (SELECT ids FROM table WHERE condition),
  actual_data AS (SELECT stuff FROM large_table WHERE id in relevant_ids)
```

I know I could use the first query and put it directly in the where condition of the second query, but I feel like this isn't very easy to read.

Comment: I think a typical use case is to build all your `WITH` objects and then do the select so you can have `WITH table1 AS (sql code), table2 AS(sql code also using table1) SELECT from objects`. Can this solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specifically address your second query...

```
WITH
  relevant_ids AS (SELECT id FROM table WHERE condition),
  actual_data AS (SELECT stuff FROM large_table WHERE id in (select id from relevant_ids))
SELECT * from actual_data
```

The code inside CTEs must still be valid SQL.

However, consider just using a join.

```
WITH
  relevant_ids AS (SELECT id FROM table WHERE condition)
SELECT 
  large_table.stuff 
FROM large_table 
INNER JOIN relevant_ids USING(id)
```